# Prove $[0,1]=\cap(-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n})$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Good morning, I have a problem with this exercise. I don't know how to prove the **question 4**, I don't know how start attack this problem.

[image]

Can someone give me some hint? Thanks.

Comment: To prove equality of sets, always the best idea is to prove both inclusions: $\subseteq$ and $\supseteq$. Both directions can be done with limit considerations.

Comment: I've noticed that you have asked several questions in a relatively short timespan. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, StackExchange software will not allow you to do so.)
For more details see [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4770/).

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to proving set equality:

---

First, prove that $$[0,1]\subseteq\bigcap_n \left(-\frac1n, 1+\frac1n\right)$$

Then, prove that $$\bigcap_n \left(-\frac1n, 1+\frac1n\right)\subseteq [0,1].$$

---

Use these facts:

- $A\subseteq B$ if and only if, for every $a\in A$, it is true that $a\in B$.
- $x\in\bigcap_n A_n$ if and only if, for every $n$, it is true that  $x\in A_n$
- $x\in (a,b)$ if and only if $x>a$ and $x< b$
- $x\in [a,b]$ if and only if $x\geq a$ and $x\leq b$.

---

For the first part of the proof:

Take any $x\in [0,1]$. Now you need to prove $$x\in \bigcap_n \left(-\frac1n, 1+\frac1n\right).$$

so you need to prove that $$\forall n\in \mathbb N: x\in \left(-\frac1n, 1+\frac1n\right)$$

Now let $n\in\mathbb N$. Now you need to prove... can you continue?

Comment: Very clearly explained. +1

Answer (score 0):

Start with assuming that $x \in [0,1]$. For any $n \in \Bbb N$, can you see that $x \in \left(-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$? Thus $x \in \bigcap\limits^{\infty}_{n=0}\left(-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$ and therefore $[0,1] \subseteq \bigcap\limits^{\infty}_{n=0}\left(-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$.

Similarly let $x \in \bigcap\limits^{\infty}_{n=0}\left(-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$. If $x < 0$, there is an $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $x \notin \left(-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$. Thus $x$ is not in the intersection.

Similarly, if $x > 1$, there is an $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $x \notin \left(-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$. Thus $x$ is not in the intersection.

So combining the above two $x \in [0,1]$. Thus  $[0,1] \supseteq \bigcap\limits^{\infty}_{n=0}\left(-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$.

Combine the results obtained to prove the equality.

Answer (score 0):

If $A \subset B_n$, then $A \subset \bigcap_{n} B_n$.

Use this fact to prove that $[0,1] \subset \bigcap_{n} \big(-\frac{1}{n}, 1+\frac{1}{n}\big)$.

To prove the inclusion other way, you need to prove that for $x < 0$ or $x > 1$, $x \notin \big(-\frac{1}{n}, 1+\frac{1}{n}\big)$ for some $n$. This means no $x$ outside $[0,1]$ is in $\bigcap_{n} \big(-\frac{1}{n}, 1+\frac{1}{n}\big)$.